# Object updated incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website using jQuery/JavaScript and the issue I am getting is: when I create several instances of aMenu, an object I made in separate file - it seems to update each of the options with the same information for each object, despite being their own variables.

**JavaScript where I create the aMenu objects:**

```
// Drawer item, animates via CSS - no need to animate using jQuery
var drawerOptions = {
  animate: false,
  toggle_element: '#parent',
  toggle_attribute: 'data-opened',
  default_toggled: false,
  toggle_after_animation: false
}
var Drawer = new aMenu(drawerOptions);

// LargeDrawer item
var largeDrawerOptions = {
  animate: false,
  toggle_element: '#parent',
  toggle_attribute: 'data-opened',
  default_toggled: false,
  toggle_after_animation: false
}
var LargeDrawer = new aMenu(largeDrawerOptions);

// Search item
var searchbarOptions = {
  animate: true,
  toggle_element: '.search_nav_drop',
  toggle_attribute: 'data-opened',
  default_toggled: false,
  toggle_after_animation: true,
  animation: 'slide'
}
var NSearchBar = new aMenu(searchbarOptions);
```

**aMenu object:**

```
  function aMenu(options){

    // Run our init if we have one.
    this.options.onInit(this);

    // Intertwine our current default options and whats being passed in.
    // Same as $.extend
    this.options = intertwine(this.options, options);

    // Determine default toggling.
    this.toggled = this.isToggled();
  }

  // Default options
  aMenu.prototype.options = {
    animate: true, // If we are animating this menu
    animation: 'slide', // Animation types: none|fade|slide|custom
    speed: 500, // Animation speed
    easing: 'linear', // Easing into the animation types: linear|swing|_default
    stop_event: false, // If the stop event is used in this case
    toggle_element: '', // This element keeps track of being toggled in HTML. Leave blank or 'none' for keeping track in JavaScript
    toggle_attribute: '', // Attribute that get toggled (true/false). Leave blank if toggle_element is blank or 'none'
    default_toggled: true, // The default selection if we are toggled or not (only used if no toggle_element)
    throw_errors: true, // If you want errors to be thrown for problem code.
    toggle_after_animation: true, // If you want the menu to toggled after the animation is completed.
    onToggle: function() {return false;}, // Function gets trigger when toggled
    onInit: function() {return false;}, // Function gets trigger at initialization
    onHide: function() {return false;}, // Function gets triggered when inactivated
    onShow: function() {return false;}, // Function gets triggered when activated
    onShowAnimationCompleted: function() {return false;}, // Function gets triggered after animation completes on show
    onHideAnimationCompleted: function() {return false;} // Function get trigger after animation completes on hide
  }
```

*Just to specify, the object Drawer will have the same options passed through as NSearchBar and the Drawer will be completely broken.*

Wasn't sure if this is an issue with prototyping, or it's just something I am completely missing. Appreciate any help is possible, thanks!

Comment: What scope are you running under? By default `this` will be the window, hence the `this.element` of the `aMenu` function will always be the `window`, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/p2ag6o8j/. From the look of your code it seems a little like you're trying to run before you can walk. What goal are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The element portion is completely meaningless - removed/updated code. It was going to be used for possible window referencing for the menu object, I am trying to simply achieve a standard class/object for the menu's to override functions and use much like an abstract class in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this.options` initially referes to `aMenu.prototype.options`

The `intertwine` (if it is the same as `$.extend`) extends and returns the target:

> Keep in mind that the target object (first argument) will be modified, and will also be returned from $.extend().

So `this.options` is the same for all instances of `aMenu`.

You need to write:

```
 this.options = $.extend({}, this.options, options)
```

This copies the properties of `this.options` which initially refers to `aMenu.prototype.options` to a new opject and then copies the properties of `options` and returns the new object which is the assigned to `this.options`.

If it would work the same with `intertwine` depends on how you implemented it.

Comment: Ermahgerd. Thanks so much!